# Адаптивный эффект затенения фона

Tags: css, background, responsive

В общем на фоновом изображении элемента есть эффект полупрозрачной тени, сделанной ::before. 
При изменении ширины окна браузера, фоновая картинка адаптируется, а фон остается фиксированной высоты, но в полном окне из-за background-size: contain фон меньше тени по высоте (изображение больше моего дисплея). Как сделать, чтобы с изображением адаптировался и эффект тени, ну и в полном окне был точно на изображении?
Вот ещё пример для лучшего понимания:
https://codepen.io/Black_Fire/pen/OgBrRO

```
    header {
  background: url('../img/bg-header.jpg') no-repeat center top;
  -webkit-background-size: contain;
          background-size: contain;
  position: relative;
  height: 810px;
  text-align: center;
}
header::before {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 60, 0.671);
  content: '';
  z-index: 100;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Надо обернуть header в специальный контейнер, который поддерживает соотношение сторон вашей картинки. Для примера вами выбрано соотношение сторон 1500:810, поэтому у контейнера padding-bottom: 54%; (810/1500 = 0.54).

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/MoPZQM

```
<div class="ratio-container">
  <header></header>
</div>

body {
  margin: 0;
}
.ratio-container {
    position: relative;
}
.ratio-container:after {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    height: 0;
    width: 100%;
    /* 810:1500 = 54% */
    padding-bottom: 54%;
}
.ratio-container > * {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: block;
}
header {
  background: url('http://lorempixel.com/1500/810/') no-repeat center top;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  text-align: center;
}
header::before {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 60, 0.671);
  content: '';
  z-index: 1;
}
```

Comment: но фон то не адаптивный

Comment: что значит - не адаптивный? он подстраивается под размеры экрана. Что есть адаптивность в вашем понимании? Показ полной картинки? Тогда задача намного сложнее - надо держать aspect ratio картинки фона. Я такое делал. Так что вы понимаете под адаптивностью?

Comment: именно показ полной картинки, а какой другой может быть адаптивность? при cover картинка обрезается.

Comment: @BlackFire адаптивность - это подстраивание размеров блоков при изменении ширины экрана. Уменьшение числа колонок при сужении, ну и т.д. Вы хотите другого.: чтобы изображение **целиком** помещалось в блок. Ок. Но в этом случае вы понимаете, что жесткое задание высоты делает задачу невыполнимой? Как, интересно, вы собираетесь отобразить картинку целиком на смартфоне с шириной экрана в 320px при жестко заданной высоте в 810px?

Comment: да это понятно, что проблема в высоте, я ведь для того и написал сюда, что может кто-то знает какой-то способ обойти это.

Comment: Завтра я покажу, как я это делал в одном проекте.

Comment: конечно можно решить как обычно делается, но вопрос был на всякий случай, вдруг выловить новый хак удалось бы.

Comment: Внес изменения в ответ.

Comment: а это как с видео с iframe.

Comment: Если ответ полезен, его стоит отметить как принятый галочкой внизу. Это поможет ориентироваться пользователям, которые ищут ответ на подобный вопрос.